# MSQ can't DELETE from same tabel as it SELECTS - Need help for workaround in my DELETE TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, delete-row

I wan't to make the trigger delete the row with the lowest ID, if it is recurring. And by recurring i mean the number and username are the same in two rows.

For example

ROW1: ID: 1 , Nr: 1 , UN: MVJ and

Row2: ID: 2 , Nr: 1 , UN: MVJ

Those are recurring, but if the 'Nr' or 'UN' were different, they wouldn't be.

But as the title explains, MYSQL can't do that, atleast with the way I've made my SQL Statement.
I'm open to solve the problem in an whole other way.

```
  Drop trigger no_double_reservations;
    DELIMITER !!
    CREATE TRIGGER no_double_reservations 
    AFTER INSERT ON tilmeldte 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF(
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM tilmeldte 
        WHERE (kursus_nr, username) 
        IN (
            SELECT kursus_nr, username 
            FROM tilmeldte 
            GROUP BY kursus_nr, username 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
            ) = 2
        )
    THEN
    DELETE FROM tilmeldte 
    Where tilmeldingsid = (
        Select MIN(`tilmeldingsid`) 
        FROM tilmeldte 
        WHERE (kursus_nr, username) 
        IN (
            SELECT MIN(kursus_nr), username 
            FROM tilmeldte 
            GROUP BY kursus_nr, username 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
            )
                          );
    END IF;
    END!!
    DELIMITER ;
```

I hope you can help.

Comment: why don't you be proactive and prevent double booking in the first place? do a check before insert, and refuse to save data with an error message already exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IF STATEMENT in DELETE TRIGGER - FAILURE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170470/if-statement-in-delete-trigger-failure)  Is this not the same question that you asked before?

Comment: @BerndLinde Not a duplicate, he is asking for **another** way, since he knows it's not working since his last question.

Comment: @krishKM Not sure how to do that in SQL.

The thing is a have to make a trigger in on of my school projects, so the whole handling of the no doubel reservations has to be in SQL. 
Purhabs the actual error-message could be in the JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given any table definition, here is a logic how to get this done in MySQL.

create stored procedure that takes your username and kursus_id
check whether the username already exists
if yes > delete and insert new id
if no > just insert new record and send message back

in code it would be something like.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_NEW_RESERVATION` (in iUsername varchar(50), in iKursus_id int)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        rollback;
        SELECT 'False' as Result, 'Some error description or diagnose description from mysql' as `Description`;
    END;

    Start Transaction;
        SET @mExists := (SELECT ID from tbl_yourTable where ((kursus_id = iKursus_id) and (username like iUsername)));
        if (length(coalesce(@mExists,'')) <> 0) then
            -- username does not exists so you can continue with insert a new reservation
            insert into tbl_yourTable and continue here

            -- send back message 
            SELECT 'True' as Result, 'New record inserted')  as `Description`;
        ELSE
            -- username exists already and the id would be saved in mExists so delete the id and continue with your insert_method
            Delete from Tbl_yourtable where id = @mExists something ligke that;
            insert into tbl_yourtable .....

            -- you can send back a message like
            SELECT 'True' as Result, concat('Old record(', @mExists, ') Deleted and new record inserted')  as `Description`;
        end if;
    Commit;

END
```

above code is incomplete. To execute this code you need to correct your insert and delete commands. Then just call the procedure like.

```
call SP_NEW_RESERVATION('KrishKm', 2);
```

if username 'KrishKm' already exists you will get message back like:

> True, Old record(10) Deleted and new record inserted.

if not you get message back:

```
True, New record inserted.
```

if anything goes wrong you get message :

```
False, 'Some error description or diagnose description from mysql'
```

Good luck.